# I need your help to in flutter list view section

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simplified this  question please have a look :---

How can I add **OnTap** event,**ICONS & TITLES** to below **List view** code

```
ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        shrinkWrap: false,
        itemCount: 200,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return listItem(context, index);
        },

Widget listItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Card(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[

      Container(margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),child: Text("1")),
      Container(height: 20,width: 1,color: Colors.blue,),
      Container(margin:EdgeInsets.all(10),child: Text("ram ram ram"))
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: underlined red errors appear from beginning to end of the page.Please paste this in your code editor for better understanding.

Comment: what error do you get when you try to run your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing your `Container`s with `ListTile`s, check out [the documentation on ListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html). It has an `onTap` parameter that you can set in order to trigger a function when a `ListTile` is tapped, and it also has `leading`, `title`, and `subtitle` parameters, where you can pass the icons and titles you need.

Another way of adding `onTap` detector to any widget is wrapping it with a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html), or an [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html), which is basically a `GestureDetector` with animations and color effects, roughly speaking. Both `GestureDetector` and `InkWell` have `onTap` parameters that you can use to detect taps and trigger functions.